# Running stanford NER classifier in server mode

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, nlp, stanford-nlp

To make the NER classification faster I am trying to execute it in server mode listerning on port xxxx, so that it can give faster result when request is send.

Here is the original execution command without server that I am using.

```
java -mx1500m -cp $1/stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier $1/classifiers/ner-eng-ie.crf-3-all2008-distsim.ser.gz -textFile $2
```

(this command is in .sh file and executed by python script. $1 is input file name)

This documentation explain how it can be run in server mode - [Link](https://github.com/dat/stanford-ner)
Here how the server get started:

```
java -mx400m -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -loadClassifier classifiers/ner-eng-ie.crf-3-all2008.ser.gz 1234
```

Now server is in listerning mode on port 1234.

**How can I make call using input text file for this server?**

I followed this tut : [Link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#cc) and executed this command:

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -port 1234 -client
```

But it just print this message:

```
Usage: NERServer [-loadFile file|-loadJarFile resource] portNumber
```

I am working on linux system.

Answer (score 2):

To run the NER in server mode, you have to use the following command line :

```
java -mx400m -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -loadClassifier classifiers/ner-eng-ie.crf-3-all2008.ser.gz -port 1234
```

(`-port` is missing  in the README file, it works well for me)

Comment: Does this run on the Stanford Server?